# Change dates to number

Tags: r, time-series

```
tsReturns = xts(x = returns, order.by = dates)
```

I have a time series ordered by date, how can I change it to order by numbers(1-n)? The first day corresponds to 1, and the last date corresponds to n. don't change the data set value.

Comment: Can the same date occur multiple times?

Comment: If you could provide a small snippet of your data using `dput` and perhaps an example of what you want to achieve that would great improve your chances of getting a helpful response

Answer (score 1):

**1)** xts does not support a plain numeric index.  It requires one of several date or datetime classes; however, a plain numeric index could be achieved with zoo or ts.  If x is an xts object and we want the plain numeric index to be consecutive numbers from 1 to nrow(x) then:

```
zoo(coredata(x))

ts(coredata(x))
```

**2)** If instead:

- the desired index of the ith row is to be the number of days since the first date plus 1 and
- the index of x is of `Date` class and
- the dates are not consecutive but are unique, e.g. there are gaps for weekends

then this will give a non-consecutive index for zoo.  Since ts can only represent regularly spaced series the ts solution below will fill in the values with NA where there is no date in the input.

```
tt <- as.numeric(time(x))
z <- zoo(coredata(x), tt - tt[1] + 1)

as.ts(z)
```